# blank line insted Undefined in new User

Tags: javascript

**
I don't want to print anything instead of "undefined"  if I have not entered value next to "user1" (course count) in new user  like : ("user1",2)

```js
        var User = function(firstName,courseCount){
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.courseCount = courseCount;
            this.getCourseCount = function(){
                console.log(`Course count is: ${this.courseCount}`);
            };
        };
        User.prototype.getFirstName = function () {
            console.log(`User Name is : ${this.firstName}`);
        };
        var user1 = new User("user1",);
        if (user1.hasOwnProperty("firstName")) {
            user1.getFirstName();
        }
        if (user1.hasOwnProperty("getCourseCount")) {
            user1.getCourseCount();
        };
```

```
    if (user1.hasOwnProperty("getCourseCount")) {
        user1.getCourseCount();
    };**
```

Comment: Try [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)? `${this.courseCount ?? ""}`

Comment: A function called `getX` should return a value, not log something and return undefined. Also, JS has actual classes now: https://jsfiddle.net/s0b85pan/

Comment: Use `this.courseCount ?? ""`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var User = function(firstName,courseCount){
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.courseCount = courseCount?courseCount:'';
            this.getCourseCount = function(){
                console.log(`Course count is: ${this.courseCount}`);
            };
        };
        User.prototype.getFirstName = function () {
            console.log(`User Name is : ${this.firstName}`);
        };
        var user1 = new User("user1",);
        if (user1.hasOwnProperty("firstName")) {
            user1.getFirstName();
        }
        if (user1.hasOwnProperty("getCourseCount")) {
            user1.getCourseCount();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var User = function(firstName,courseCount){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.courseCount = courseCount;
        this.getCourseCount = function(){
 if(this.courseCount===undefined){this.courseCount=""}
            console.log(`Course count is: ${this.courseCount}`);
        };
    };
```

> this will prevent to print undefined